# Cognos authentication using Custom Java Provider problem

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I've write a Cognos authentication using Custom Java Provider which is working well for Analytics server.

When I use windows clients  (Report Framework Manager and  Dynamic cube and Transformer) to login Analytics server，
they did redirect to my custom login page. But no SSO  effect.

How to use the Custom Java Provider in  Report Framework Manager and  Dynamic cube and Transformer.

Anyone who did this before can give me some tips ?

What should I set or config ?

Comment: Far as I know, SSO will only work in browsers, not stand-alone tools. You would have to code your authentication provider to allow users to log into it directly, instead of through SSO.  That's not trivial.

Comment: I  have another question ,  I set a  login  redirect  URL  for SSO  in  Analytics server https://imgur.com/zNv7Sr1 

But  it will make those client tools  login behaver  be changed too (Client login UI be changed)   How  to  make  the  login  redirect  URL   doesn't  interfere   client tools  login behaver

Comment: I want to give up SSO for windows client tools , let it login behaver as it default setting(let client tools login from origin UI, not my custom login page). And  make SSO  works  in  Analytics Server(Web browser). How to change Custom Java Provider  or set configurations to achieve those objective.

Comment: Set  the redirect URL https://imgur.com/zNv7Sr1 , make SSO Works , But  4 client tools (Report Framework Manager and Dynamic cube and Transformer, Cognos for Office) have 4 type  login  behavers and SSO doesn't work.  IBM  should take it as a serious  problem.

Comment: https://cogknowhow.tm1.dk/archives/1149   You are right, Andrew.